# Class Template Derived from Another Class Template Type Deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae, template-argument-deduction

I am trying to write a functor memoizer to save time on repeated expensive function calls.  In my class design I am struggling to find a simple interface.

Using this Functor base class:

```
template <typename TOut, typename TIn>
class Functor {
public:
    virtual
    ~Functor() {
    }

    virtual
    TOut operator()(TIn input) = 0;
};
```

I now want to write a class that will encapsulate and memoize a functor.  In addition to encapsulating a `Functor`, the `MemoizedFunctor` will itself be a `Functor`.  This results in having 3 template parameters.

Here is a working example:

```
#include <unordered_map>

template <typename F, typename TOut, typename TIn>
class MemoizedFunctor : public Functor<TOut, TIn> {
public:
    MemoizedFunctor(F f) : f_(f) {
    }

    virtual
    ~MemoizedFunctor() {
    }

    virtual
    TOut operator()(TIn input) override {
        if (cache_.count(input)) {
            return cache_.at(input);
        } else {
            TOut output = f_(input);
            cache_.insert({input, output});
            return output;
        }
    }

private:
    F f_;
    std::unordered_map<TIn, TOut> cache_;
};

class YEqualsX : public Functor<double, double> {
public:
    virtual
    ~YEqualsX() {
    }

    double operator()(double x) override {
        return x;
    }
};

int main() {
    MemoizedFunctor<YEqualsX, double, double> f((YEqualsX())); // MVP

    f(0); // First call
    f(0); // Cached call

    return 0;
}
```

I feel like there MUST be a way to eliminate having to specify all 3 template parameters.  Given the function passed to the constructor of `MemoizedFunctor`, I would argue that all three template parameters could be deduced.

I am not sure how to rewrite the class so that using it would not require all the template specification.

I tried using a smart pointer to a Functor as the member variable in `MemoizedFunctor`.  This eliminates the first template parameter, but now the user of the class must pass a smart pointer to the `MemoizedFunctor` class.

In summary, I would like to have all the template arguments of `MemoizedFunctor` be automatically be deduced on construction.  I believe this is possible because on construction all template arguments are unambiguous.

Comment: You're flipping the in/out parameters - can you pick a consistent ordering?

Comment: @Barry Whoops sorry about that, hopefully it's fixed now.  Mistake made when transposing from one machine to this machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In summary, I would like to have all the template arguments of MemoizedFunctor be automatically be deduced on construction. I believe this is possible because on construction all template arguments are unambiguous.

If I understand correctly, the first template type for `MemoizedFunctor` is ever a `Functor<TOut, TIn>`, or something that inherit from some `Functior<TOut, TIn>`, where `TOut` and `TIn` are second and third template parameter for `MemoizedFunctor`.

It seems to me that you're looking for a deduction guide.

To deduce the second and third template parameter, I propose to declare (no definition is required because are used only inside `decltype()`) the following couple of functions

```
template <typename TOut, typename TIn>
constexpr TIn getIn (Functor<TOut, TIn> const &);

template <typename TOut, typename TIn>
constexpr TOut getOut (Functor<TOut, TIn> const &);
```

Now, using `decltype()` and `std::declval()`, the user defined deduction guide simply become

```
template <typename F>
MemoizedFunctor(F)
   -> MemoizedFunctor<F,
                      decltype(getOut(std::declval<F>())),
                      decltype(getIn(std::declval<F>()))>;
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <unordered_map>

template <typename TOut, typename Tin>
class Functor
 {
   public:
    virtual ~Functor ()
     { }

    virtual TOut operator() (Tin input) = 0;
 };

template <typename TOut, typename TIn>
constexpr TIn getIn (Functor<TOut, TIn> const &);

template <typename TOut, typename TIn>
constexpr TOut getOut (Functor<TOut, TIn> const &);

template <typename F, typename TOut, typename TIn>
class MemoizedFunctor : public Functor<TOut, TIn>
 {
   public:
      MemoizedFunctor(F f) : f_{f}
       { }

      virtual ~MemoizedFunctor ()
       { }

      virtual TOut operator() (TIn input) override
       {
         if ( cache_.count(input) )
            return cache_.at(input);
         else
          {
            TOut output = f_(input);
            cache_.insert({input, output});
            return output;
          }
       }

   private:
      F f_;
      std::unordered_map<TIn, TOut> cache_;
 };

class YEqualsX : public Functor<double, double>
 {
   public:
      virtual ~YEqualsX ()
       { }

      double operator() (double x) override
       { return x; }
 };

template <typename F>
MemoizedFunctor(F)
   -> MemoizedFunctor<F,
                      decltype(getOut(std::declval<F>())),
                      decltype(getIn(std::declval<F>()))>;

int main ()
 {
   MemoizedFunctor f{YEqualsX{}};

   f(0); // First call
   f(0); // Cached call
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

Aschepler, in a comment, observed that there is a possible drawback in this solution: some types can't be returned from a function.

By example, a function can't return a C-style array.

This ins't a problem deducing `TOut` (the type returned by `operator()`) exactly because is a type returned by a method so is returnable also by `getOut()`.

But this can be (generally speaking) a problem for `TIn`: if `TIn` is, by example, `int[4]` (can't be, in this case, because is used as a key for an unordered map but, I repeat, generally speaking), a `int[4]` can't returned by `getIn()`.

You can go around this problem (1) adding a type wrapper struct as follows

```
template <typename T>
struct typeWrapper
 { using type = T; };
```

(2) modifying `getIn()` to return the wrapper `TIn`

```
template <typename TOut, typename TIn>
constexpr typeWrapper<TIn> getIn (Functor<TOut, TIn> const &);
```

and (3) modifying the deduction guide to extract `TIn` from the wrapper

```
template <typename F>
MemoizedFunctor(F)
   -> MemoizedFunctor<F,
                      decltype(getOut(std::declval<F>())),
                      typename decltype(getIn(std::declval<F>()))::type>;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!  This looks to accomplish exactly what I was hoping for.  I will take a closer look at it tomorrow to try to understand it all.

Comment: One drawback about this function declaration method in general is that some C++ types (raw arrays, abstract classes, function types) can never be a function return type. Not really an issue for this example, since `Functor<TOut, TIn>::operator()` already used them as a return type and parameter type.

Comment: @aschepler - good point; surely not an issue for `TOut`, because is the returned type for `operator()` so is returnable; but maybe is an issue for `TIn`: if `TIn` is (by example) `int[4]`, `operator()` can receive it but `getIn()` can't return it. Uhmmm... maybe I'll add a caveat.

Comment: @aschepler - Thinking a little about the problem, there is a simple solution: return the `TIn` type, from `getIn()`, wrapped in a struct. Thanks for pointing the problem.

Comment: @Pavis11 - aschepler has pointed a possible problem in my solution; answer modified to go around it (but give a look also at the Barry solution: if you can add a couple of `using` aliases in the `Functor` base classes, all become a lot simpler).

Answer (score 4):

In:

```
template <typename F, typename TOut, typename TIn>
class MemoizedFunctor : public Functor<TOut, TIn> { ... }
```

If `F` *must* be an implementation of `Functor` (which I'm guessing is the case?), you can add a few aliases to `Functor` to make your life easier (these can be done externally instead of internally, but it seems reasonable to make this intrusive):

```
template <typename TOut, typename TIn>
class Functor {
public:
    using in_param = TIn;
    using out_param = TOut;
    // ... rest as before ...
};
```

And then change `MemoizedFunctor` to use those aliases directly. You don't *really* have independent template parameters, they're completely dependent right?

```
template <typename F>
class MemoizedFunctor : public Functor<typename F::out_param, typename F::in_param> { ... }
```

With that change (and likewise change your interal use of `TOut` and `TIn`), this works as desired (since, of course, we only have one template parameter now so there's only one to provide):

```
MemoizedFunctor<YEqualsX> f(YEqualsX{});
```

And that parameter can be deduced through CTAD directly without any further changes

```
MemoizedFunctor f(YEqualsX{});
```

Comment: Your assumption that `F` must also be an implementation of `Functor` is correct.  I was thinking a solution similar to this must exist since as you said I don't really have 3 independent template parameters.  I actually tried this solution without the aliases (`class MemoizedFunctor : public Functor<typename F::TOut, typename F::TIn>`), but of course this didn't work.  I knew this syntax was funky and it looks like these aliases are the solution.